# Нужна помощь с вёрсткой кнопки

Tags: css, css3

Как лучше всего сверстать кнопку "WORK WITH US!"? У меня что-то не получается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что конкретно у вас не получается ? создаете `button` и стилизируете его.
Или лучше прикрепите ваш код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #86509c;
}

a {
  padding: 1.25rem 3.75rem;
  background-color: #eb7d4a;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 rgb(192, 103, 77);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Work with us!</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает, а как работает box-shadow и transition можете объяснить, пожалуйста?

Comment: Maref box-shadow и transition достаточно вбить в поисковик

Comment: Я transition случайно оставил, так как тестил различные анимации при нажатии, но потом подумал, что это тебя запутает ещё сильнее и убрал, а transition забыл.box-shadow конкретно в этом примере: 1 цифра - сдвиг тени по горизонтали(0), 2 цифра - сдвиг тени по вертикали(3px), 3 цифра - размытие тени(0), четвёртое значение - цвет тени в формате rgb.Есть ещё одно значение, которого нет в примере, но его я думаю ты нагуглишь уже сам.

Answer (score 0):

box-shadow это тень вокруг элемента(кнопка, блок, картинка), можно и внутрь сделать подсветку например в поле импута, есть онлайн настройка теней даже в инете.
transition это время выполнения анимации или ховер эфекта( изменение блока, кнопки (цвет, размер, яркость) при наведении например).

Answer (score 0):

У меня есть вариант:

```
<div class="col lg-6" id="waveBtn">
            <button class="fcss waveBtn">Click Me!</button>

                </div>
#waveBtn{
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
.fcss.waveBtn{
    border: none;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    background-color: #00BCD4;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: 0.2s;
    z-index: 2;
}
.fcss.waveBtn:after{
    content: 'Click Me!';
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff; 
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0px;
    border-radius: 0% 0% 50% 50%; 
    opacity: 0;
}
.fcss.waveBtn:hover:after{
    animation: fallen 0.3s linear forwards;
}
.fcss.waveBtn:hover{
    color: #000;
}
@keyframes fallen{
    0%{
        height: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0% 0% 100% 100%;
    }
    90%{
        border-radius: 0% 0% 10% 10%;
    }
    100%{
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #FFC107;
        opacity: 1;
        border-radius: 0%;
    }
}
```